# set maxResults with JIRA REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I wonder how to set maxResults using jql?

Here is my query:
search?jql=project%20=%20SYTLK%20AND%20maxResults=500

And here is the result:

{"errorMessages":["Field 'maxResults' does not exist or you do not have permission to view it."],"errors":{}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`maxResults` is a query parameter, not a JQL-related keyword.

`/search?jql=[JQL_string]&maxResults=500`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try post type for your request!

**Json format:**

```
{
    "jql": "project = HSP",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 15,
    "fields": [
        "summary",
        "status",
        "assignee"
    ]
}
```

---

Ref: https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.10.1/#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest